# Solving an equation with integrals

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve an equation in Python where the unknown is "trapped" within an integral which is itself defined over another variable.

[image: click to see the integral]

I tried different way of coding but without any success so far...

Here is the simplest code I tried:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import root

c = 10

f = lambda x, y: norm.pdf(y-x)
eq = lambda x, y: quad(f, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(y))[0] - c
sol = root(eq, x0=0)

print('x =', int(sol.x[0]))
```

But after running the code, I have this error: 
() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

So I tried to change the last line with:

```py
sol = lambda x, y: root(eq, x0=0, args=(y))
```

or

```py
sol = lambda y: root(eq, x0=0, args=(y))
```

But I do not know whether it works or not, and if so, how can I get back the solution in a variable?

Many thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: Can you put an image or readable way of the integral ? It would help

Comment: @DavidE I just put a link to see the integral! Thx :)

Comment: Why are you trying to solve this with code?